# dice random value 1 to 10 and overthrow in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, random

Hi I have code like this:

```
 $('#Generator_Rzutow').click (function(){
    var val1 = $('#rzucane').val();
    var val2 = $('#zachowywane').val();
    var zbior = [];
    var limit = 10;
    alert (val1);
    alert (val2); 
    for (var i=0; i<val1;i++){
        var wynik_rzutu = 1+Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
        if (wynik_rzutu<limit){
            zbior.push(wynik_rzutu);
            } else {
                    limit = limit+10;
                    wynik_rzutu = wynik_rzutu+1+Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
                    if (wynik_rzutu<limit){
                zbior.push(wynik_rzutu);
                } else {
                        limit = limit+10;
                        wynik_rzutu = wynik_rzutu+1+Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
                        zbior.push(wynik_rzutu);
                    }
            }
        }
    $('#wypisz').text (zbior);  
  });
```

My problem is that when it randoms '10' it sometimes add 10 to array, when it should randomize another time and ad it to prev value.

My second question is. How to get it to randomize another value and ad it to prev as long as it randomize 10. For ex: so it could get numer 74, when it randomize 7x10 and 4, and then it past it to array.

I know I should do it by while lop but I couldn`t get working solition, so instead I put 'if'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you don't reset your limit at each iteration. You start with limit 10, then when the first number larger than 10 is generated, the limit is increased to 20 and all subsequent numbers will be compared to 20 to see if they are added to the array or re-generated (and they will all be added to the array, since they are all smaller than 20).

As for your second problem, i think this piece of code behaves accordingly:

```
for (var i=0; i<val1;i++){
  var wynik_rzutu = 0, limit = 0;
  while (wynik_rzutu >= limit) {
    wynik_rzutu += 1+Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    limit += 10;
  }
  zbior.push(wynik_rzutu);
}
```

You can also add a counter to prevent it from an infinite cycle (if Math.random() always returns 0.9 for example), but i doubt it is something you really require.

Comment: += is a shorthand for x = x + y